# Proving vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in an upper division linear algebra course. In my textbook it states:

Let $S=\left\{(a_1,a_2): a_1, a_2 \text{ is a member of } R\right\}$.For $(a_1,a_2), (b_1,b_2)$ is a member of $S$ and $c$ is a member of $R$, define:

$$(a_1,a_2)+ (b_1,b_2)= (a_1+b_1, a_2-b_2)$$ and $$c(a_1,a_2)= (ca_1,ca_2).$$

The book states that these axioms of the vector spaces fail to hold which are:

1) $\forall x,y \in V, x+y= y+x$

2) $\forall x,y,z \in V, (x+y)+z= x+(y+z)$

3) for each pair of elements $a, b \in F$ and each $x \in V$, $(a+b)x= ax+bx$.

*$F$= field

$V$= vector space

$R$= Field of real real numbers

I really need helping proving why these 3 axioms do not hold. I believe I have an idea on how to prove the first one, but how do you prove the 2nd and 3rd one if I only have $2$ pairs of vectors, instead of $3$?

Thanks.

Comment: It will make your post *much* more readable if you took the time to look to see how it displays.  A single return character (enter key) does not start a new line here, but rather two return characters are needed.  Also, by using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$ you can write things more clearly using standard notation such as $S=\{(a_1,a_2)~:~a_1,a_2\in\Bbb R\}$

Comment: For the second property for example, check to see if $[(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)]+(c_1,c_2) = (a_1,a_2)+[(b_1,b_2)+(c_1,c_2)]$ in every case, or if there is a counterexample.  Similarly for the third property, check to see if $(x+y)(a_1,a_2) = x(a_1,a_2)+y(a_1,a_2)$.  (*how about when $x=0$ and $y=1$*?)

Comment: I know what a real number is but what is a real real numbers?

Comment: @Bob they are the real numbers that aren't fake real numbers